# Geopandas Proj4 reproject to global equal area projection

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, geopandas

I have a geoDataFrame with crs `{'init': 'epsg:4326'}` The data has a global extent and my goal is to calculate the area (in m2) per feature. Therefore I want to [reproject](http://geopandas.org/projections.html?highlight=reproject#re-projecting) the geoDataFrame using the

```
gdf.to_crs({'init':'epsg:xxxx'})
```

method. I looked into suitable global equal area projections and found Eckert IV. However I cannot find an EPSG code for this [projection](http://epsg.io/54012). Is there a way to

1. use an ESRI code in geopandas (proj4 under the hood) e.g. ESRI:54012 ? or should I
2. use another global equal area projection crs for which an epsg is available.

EDIT: using the proj4 definition string works. Make sure you click proj4 and not just copy the definition on top. (without the `+ellps=WGS84` part). 
[Notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/rutgerhofste/b174e4c8fa4c9a2ad40e60bb2e482c0c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `to_crs` method also accepts the full proj4 string specification (or in dictionary presentation), so you can do

```
gdf = gdf.to_crs("+proj=eck4 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

without the need for an EPSG code (proj4 definition from https://epsg.io/54012)

Comment: Thanks, I copied the definition string from the top of the page which contains an extra '+ellps=WGS84'. Now it works. See notebook attached.

Comment: This was by far the easiest volume to flux conversion ever. Thanks geopandas. It would be great to add an example using a proj4 string in the docs: http://geopandas.org/projections.html#setting-a-projection